# How to automate gmail to send email by using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, gmail

I'm trying to automate gmail with selenium to automatically send email as a proof of concept for my boss, but I can't make it to click on the send button.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Try click_at instead of click. Possibly try clicking higher on the dom tree, eg on the parent of the button.

Comment: thanx you soo much, it work, by the way i would like to send my email with attach it's possible? cheers..

Comment: Probably, if the Selenium keyboard robot will click the file dialog that comes up. Have not tried that.

Comment: i try it but , when recording if I click on attach file no command is recorded..i'm confused

Comment: Thanks surya for this solution, i was facing same problem in my script.
That is solved now.
Earlier my script is not detecting compose and send button click event.
Now send button click event is resolved but still facing the problem for compose button click event.
can you please suggest me a solution for same?

Comment: Use 'keyPress' or 'clickAt' command.Using 'clickAt' you can click on compose:

clickAt | //div[text()='COMPOSE'] | 1,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach a file, try following Se IDE code:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//span[text()='Attach a file']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=.LIODqc</td>
    <td>C:\Path\To\file.txt</td>
</tr>
```

Updated for entering data in 'To', 'Subject', Attachment, mail body and then sending mail:

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=to</td>
    <td>surya.dixit@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=subject</td>
    <td>testSubject</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//span[text()='Attach a file']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=.LIODqc</td>
    <td>C:\Path\To\file.txt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=body[class='editable  LW-avf']</td>
    <td>Surya</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>keyPress</td>
    <td>//div/b[text()='Send']</td>
    <td>13</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanx you so much , but i can't send the mail attach until now. sometings wrong in my code? please   <tr> <td>click</td> <td>//span[text()='Attach a file']</td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td>type</td> <td>css=.LIODqc</td> <td>/home/user/test.txt</td> </tr> <tr> <td>pause</td> <td>10000</td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td>clickAt</td> <td>//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/‌​div/div/</td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td>pause</td> <td>3000</td> <td></td> </tr>

Comment: Great great it works thanx by the way in my email i can't write something of the body of my email, , for receiver i used type  name=to and for subject i used name= subjet, it's working but of the body i did located the xPath?? ideas?,

Comment: thanx you so much, but i don't know i have this error:![error] Element css=body[class='editable LW-avf'] not found, i forgot something?? i use firefox.

Comment: I believe, in your css locator one space is missing between two class names(editable & LW-avf), as there are 2 spaces in between them. Try exact css locator provided in my answer.

Comment: Hello guys I still have a question about selenium, I suppose
you receive a mail and you want to read the mail. how can i automated this reading? 
now i can log into gmail click on the box of reception but when i click on the email
that i would like to read no cammand recorded in the selenium IDE.can i use the coordiantes 
(X, Y)? any ideas? cheers

Comment: hello i cand send email with one attach but i would like to send it with three attach here my code java  selenium.click("//span[text()='Joindre un fichier']");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  selenium.type("css=.LIODqc", "/usr/share/example-content/Trigonométrie.xls");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  selenium.click("//span[text()='Joindre un autre fichier']");
  selenium.type("css=.LIODqc", "/usr/share/example-content/Échéancier-paiement.ods");
  
  selenium.click("//span[text()='Joindre un autre fichier']");
;  now only one file is send beacause it use only css=.LIODqc don't have another solution??

Comment: In that case use other locating strategy; you can use following xpath to locate each file input field - //descendant::input[@class='LIODqc'][2]  -- Just change the index number to get required file field.That is, this xpath will locate a 2nd file input field.